# Extension do not load file from integration.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing my extension using React+Typescript. My integration files are .js.
This is part of my intergation json.

"myjetbrains.com": {
    "name": "Myjetbrains",
    "link": "*://*.myjetbrains.com/*",
    "script": "youtrack.js",
    "clone": false
  }

And in my youtrack.js now I have only console.log to test. But when I open https://parampampam.myjetbrains.com/... it do nothing. May be I got problem that I do not update my json file, but I tryed to rebuild my app, and so on. May be someone can help? Thanks in forward!!!

Comment: I see nothing in the question that's specific to chrome extension so I guess you should add some tags for the framework or tool you're using to make the question visible to people who can help.

Comment: @wOxxOm nothing specicfic? seriously? I'm asking about why my "extension" integration cannot load scripts?

Comment: Yes, seriously. It means the question doesn't contain any information specific to extensions in particular.

Comment: @wOxxOm well, may be it is my mistake)) 
but I still found a solution and it was quite easy)))

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution is :remove extension from chrome, and then reinstall(Load unpacked)